# Drop a group after groupby based on the presence of a value in a column in the group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

On `0.24.1`, given:

```
toy = pd.DataFrame({'g': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3], 'val': [0,2,3,4,5,6,0]})
toy
   g  val
0  1    0
1  1    2
2  1    3
3  2    4
4  2    5
5  3    6
6  3    0
```

I want to drop entire groups where the `v` column of the group contains a zero. In other words, after the incantation, which should preferably involve `inplace=True` to preserve my data transformation pipeline, I want `toy` to be:

```
   g  val
3  2    4
4  2    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `filter`

```
toy.groupby('g').filter(lambda x : all(x['val']!=0))
Out[58]: 
   g  val
3  2    4
4  2    5
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can also do:

```
toy[~toy.g.isin(toy.loc[toy.val.eq(0),'g'])]

   g  val
3  2    4
4  2    5
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
toy.loc[toy.groupby('g').transform(np.prod).query('val !=0').index, :]
```